# Nested loop with different Magick command in bat Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert many pdf files into jpg but only if it has 1 page. I rather work with multi-pages pdf than images. I tried different command and get them working correctly individually, both `identify` and `convert`. However, I couldn't combine them to work in a folder. I haven't got to the point of conditional operation (if less than 2 pages, convert it). I am using this code

```
pause
set path="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\";%path%
FOR /r %%g in (*.pdf) DO (
    for /f %%i in ('identify -format %n %%g') do set pgs=%%i
    echo %pgs%
echo "%%g"
::convert %%~ng%%~xg %%~ng.jpg
::del %%~ng.pdf
)
pause
```

It says the syntax of the command is incorrect. The commented out part is working correctly. I don't know command line very well so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using Powershell instead?

Comment: You'lll need to use http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html when setting **and** using a variable inside a `(code block)`.

Comment: You are treating the `FOR` variables like the files are all in the current working directory.  The `/R` option of the `FOR` command recurses directories.  This means you have to use `%%g` as the input for the commands you are running because it includes the full path to the file.

Comment: @LotPings I just add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top but it still say that syntax incorrect.

Comment: Instead of setting the number of pages to a variable just use an `IF` command instead. `for /f %%i in ('identify -format %n %%g') do if %%i geq 2 convert "%%g" "%%~dpng.jpg"`

Comment: @Squashman Now it return `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~ng%%~xg %%~ng.jpg`

Comment: You are missing a percent symbol in your code. But like I said, you should be using `%%g` for the input file as it contains the path to the file as well. Did you try my example above?

Comment: @Squashman I copied exactly and run. The comment is the result.

Comment: @TamLe, looks like you are still using your old code. Look at my code again.

Comment: @Squashman IIUR the requirement is to convert if the pdf has only one page, so `for /f %%i in ('identify -format %n "%%g"') do if %%i equ 1 convert "%%g" "%%~dpng.jpg"`

Comment: @LotPings, completely brain farted on that. Looking at the code I am thinking the percent symbol for the format option might have to be doubled as well.  At least that is normally what needs to be done when a literal percent symbol needs to be passed to another command.

Comment: @Squashman I did test it (needed to use `magick identify %n "%%g"` though)

Comment: @LotPings can you show the full working code from your end? I have not able to replicate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the final code that works. It does a lot of little things

- Loops through folders and subfolders
- Evaluate every pdf file
- If the pdf file does NOT have "*c*" in its name AND have more than 1 page, rename at "*c*" after its name before the extension. (This help avoid process processed files)

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

```
pause 
set path="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\";%path%

FOR /d /R %%i in (*) DO ( 

    cd "%%i"
        FOR /r %%g in (*.pdf) DO (
        (Echo "%%g" | FIND /I "_c_" 1>NUL )||(
            for /f %%i in ('magick identify -format %%n "%%g"') do if %%i gtr 1 ren %%~ng%%~xg %%~ng_c_%%~xg
)
)
cd..
)
pause
```

Comment: Wow, posting a working code actually get minuses. I know it's not the greatest code in the world and solve a small number of small problems, nothing cutting edge. Just try to contribute, still get to wonder why do I get minuses? Any admin to answer?